# Pandas Pivot Table - How to show columns with no values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get my pivot table to show each month, even if there is no values there.  Here is what I get today with data types below the pivot table.  The column heading represents the month # (which I would like to change to the act month as well i.e. 1 = "Jan", etc.).

```
            PART NUMBER          
Month Baseline        4.0  5.0  10.0
EPA Status                          
Completed               36    0    5
In Process              17    0    0
Not Required             1    0    0
Not Started             37    1    0


Month Baseline
PART NUMBER  4.0               int64
             5.0               int64
             10.0              int64
```

Here is what I would like to see:

```
                 PART NUMBER          
Month Baseline         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0...12.0
EPA Status                          
Completed               0    0    0    36    0    5     0
In Process              0    0    0    17    0    0     0
Not Required            0    0    0     1    0    0     0
Not Started             0    0    0    37    1    0     0
```

Here is my code below.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np

from ChooseFileGUI import choose_file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel(choose_file(), "Data Input")  # define DataFrame "df" from Excel File, Worksheet 
"Data Input"

df["EPA Status"] = df["EPA Status"].astype("category")

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]  # 
month list

gear_shaft_filter = df[(df["Sub Team"] == "GEAR/SHAFT") &  # change Sub Team name to suit
                       (df["InScope (Y/N)"] == "YES") &  # change to NO to see out of scope
                       (df["EPA PM Forecast Completion Year"] == 2020)]  # change or add years as 
                                                                           required

pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(gear_shaft_filter,
                          index=["EPA Status"],
                          values=["PART NUMBER"],
                          columns=["Month Baseline"],
                          aggfunc=np.count_nonzero,
                          fill_value=0)
```

Comment: I haven't tested but try changing the aggfunc to  pivot_df.count

Comment: the parameters in the pivot_df won't let me add **aggfunc=pivot_df.count()** to it.  Is this where you were referencing to change it?

Comment: Correct, although I believe you don't need the parentheses when passing it as an argument.,

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct but I still can't pass it as an argument.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It may be a simple as passing 'count' (without the single quotes)

Comment: just tried that and I can't pass 'count" (without the single quotes)